# Why asm generated by gcc mov twice?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Suppose I have the following C code:
    #include

```
int main()
{
    int x = 11;
    int y = x + 3;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it into asm using gcc, I get this(with some flag removed):

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $11, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $3, %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

My problem is why it is `movl -4(%rbp), %eax` followed by `movl %eax, %esi`, rather than a simple `movl -4(%rbp), %esi`(which works well according to my experiment)?

Comment: Did you enable optimizations?

Comment: [This is your code](https://godbolt.org/g/Mh0ibK) with `-Os` option... Try to change it to `-O0` and see what happen

Comment: @MarcGlisse No, I didn't.

Comment: Well, it's amazing. With optimazition, the outcome is huge.

Comment: @Richard Without optimization, gcc is quite naive, makes no attempt to be clever, and generates code that is as straight forward translation from C as it can.

Comment: @nos Yea, but why does gcc move twice? Since a single move would work.

Comment: gcc does 2 things: read x from memory, and store that in the ABI-mandated place for a function call. Without optimization, it does not try to merge those two steps.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Got, thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably did not enable optimizations.

Without optimization the compiler will produce code like this. For one it does **not** allocate data to registers, but on the stack. This means that when you operate on variables they will first be transferred to a register and then operated on.

So given that `x` lives is allocated in `-4(%rbp)` and this is what the code appears as if you translate it directly without optimization. First you move `11` to the storage of `x`. This means:

```
movl    $11, -4(%rbp)
```

done with the first statement. The next statement is to evaluate `x+3` and place in the storage of `y` (which is `-8(%rbp)`, this is done without regard of the previous generated code:

```
movl     -4(%rbp), %eax
addl     $3, %eax
movl     %eax, -8(%rbp)
```

done with the second statement. By the way that is divided into two parts: evaluation of `x+3` and the storage of the result. Then the compiler continues to generate code for the `printf` statement, again without taking earlier statements into account.

If you on the other hand would enable optimization the compiler does a number of smart and to humans obvious things. One thing is that it allows variables to be allocated to registers, or at least keep track on where one can find the value of the variable. In this case the compiler would for example know in the second statement that `x` is not only stored at `-4(%ebp)` it will also know that it is stored in `$11` (yes it nows it's actual value). It can then use this to add `3` to it which means it knows the result to be `14` (but it's smarter that that - it has also seen that you didn't use that variable so it skips that statement entirely). Next statement is the `printf` statement and here it can use the fact that it knows `x` to be `11` and pass that directly to `printf`. By the way it also realizes that it doesn't get to use the storage of `x` at `-4(%ebp)`. Finally it may know what `printf` does (since you included `stdio.h`) so can analyze the format string and do the conversion at compile time to replace the `printf` statement to a call that directly writes `14` to standard out.

Comment: Nice explanation. But waht I want to know is that why does gcc first move `-4(%rbp)` to `%eax`, and then movl `%eax, %esi,`, instead of giving a straightforward `mov` from `-4(%rbp)` to `%esi`?

Comment: @Richard That may look a bit odd at first, but it's about how the compiler breaks down the expression and generates code one piece at a time. First it evaluates `x` then places the result in the proper place for paremeter passing. The `mov -4(%rbp), %eax` is the evaluation of `x` (where the result of the expression is placed in `%eax`), then the result is placed at the proper place for argument passing, in this case `%esi`.